# Replace HREF with hash if URL contains specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, href

In my home page I have links in a pattern.
The URLs have `portfolio-item` in the href.

Ex:

1. www.mysite.com/portfolio-item/whatEver1
2. www.mysite.com/portfolio-item/whatEver2
3. www.mysite.com/portfolio-item/whatEver3

For now I have to find if a URL has the word `portfolio-item`or not.
If `portfolio-item` is found then I have to relace the href to `#`

What I mean is:

If the anchor tag is `<a href="www.mysite.com/portfolio-item/whatEver">What Ever</a>`what ever I have to change it to `<a href="#">what ever</a>`

Because the above HREF has the word `portfolio-item`.

How can I check the all the anchor tags which are in page and check for the word `portfolio-item` and if it is found then replace the href value to `#` using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('a[href*="portfolio-item"]').attr('href', '#');
```

The selector `a[href*="portfolio-item"]` will select all the `<a>` elements whose `href` attribute value contains the string `portfolio-item` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer with proper explanation. That works like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkArray = ["portfolio-item", "if AnyOther Thing Too can come here"];
for(var i=0; i<checkArray.length; i++) {
    $('a[href*="'+checkArray[i]+'"]').attr('href', "#");
}
```

you can utilize this for multiple urls.

Comment: I do not know how many links are there. So basically the code should automatically find the `href`s which have the word `portfolio-item`